# Template does not exist - Django

Tags: python, django, templates, path

I'm trying to create  an `index.html` by extending `base.html`. The problem is, that `Django` says that there is no such template. It can't find it. I've already tried more paths but none of them worked.

This is my **project structure:**
[image]

**Uploading/templates/Uploading/index.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="/process_text/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ lang_drop_down_form }}
        <br>
        {{ text_area_form }}
        {{ file_upload_form }}
        <input align="center" type="submit" value="upload">
    </form>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Hello {{ user.name }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**uploading/templates/uploading/base.html:** (jumbotron bootstrap template)

```
.
..
...
    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
      </div>
    </div>
...
..
.
```

And the exception:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
mysite/uploading/templates/uploading/base.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
mysite/uploading/templates/uploading/base.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py in find_template, line 146
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Milano\\PycharmProjects\\mysite',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Sun, 20 Dec 2015 15:08:11 +0100
```

Do you know what to do?

Comment: in your settings.py there should be a name of the folder used for templates. Which one is that?

Comment: There is only this: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your extends tag to:

```
{% extends 'uploading/base.html' %}
```

The template is in `uploading/templates/uploading/base.html`. The app template dir is `uploading/templates`, so you need to use the remainder, `uploading/base.html` when referring to it in Django.